# Windows Phone Multiple Pages Vs 1 Page

Tags: windows-phone

I have an application where I require a lot of Pages but I am wondering if it could be at all possible to dynamically change ONE page.

The pages will essentially have the exact same objects, however, the properties of those objects will be different. For example:

Each page will have a background, but each background will be different. Each page will have certain images but the image source will be different among all images.

I have an architecture in place that contains these properties, I just need to know how to feed in the object associated with the specific page. Something like Bindings i guess..

Does anyone have a clear idea on how to achieve this? I don't wish to make lots and lots of images and keep adding stuff on to it... That would be too expensive and time consuming.

Comment: So you mean that you would create one page in code that you would navigate to when when changing contexts, or you only ever want to have one instance of a page running at a time when in your app?

Comment: Meaning, I would want ONE page to continuously take in a ViewModel and update the UI. Instead of making x amount of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Windows Phone Pivot Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/) may be exactly what you are looking for.
With a little coding, you should be able to accomplish your objectives using this control.